# CSS: border-radius // insert a background; white corners

Tags: html, css

So I'm totally new to HTML/CSS. I'm designing a fun project now to learn web development.
I created a search bar and wanted to add the famous round corners with border-radius. So far it works good. The problem is that the white background shines through the edges now, since the search bar is located in the menu bar.
I will post a screenshot and the code below. I'm not 100% familiar with the CSS box-model. I guess there lies the problem. Maybe I can fill the void with my menu background image? Hope someone can guide me where to fix this problem.

Screenshot:
https://picload.org/view/prwpirg/bildschirmfoto2015-09-20um16.3.png.html

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #EAEDF5;
}

.headerMenu {
    background-image: url("../img/menu_bg.png");
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    background-image: url("../img/menu_bg.png");
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.logo {
    background-image: url("../img/menu_bg.png");
    width: 125px;
}

.logo img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
}

.search_box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 17px;
    margin-left: 150px;
}

#search input[type="text"] {
    background: url(../img/search_white.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #D8D8D8;
    outline: none;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 35px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}

#search input[type="text"]:focus {
    background: url(../img/search_black.png) no-repeat 10px 6pc #fcfcfc;
    color: #6a6f75;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

/*...*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>facefuck</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="headerMenu">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="./img/face_logo.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="search_box">
                    <form action="search.php" method="GET" id="search">
                        <input type="text" name="q" size="60" placeholder="Search..." />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="menu">
                    <a href="#" />Home</a>
                    <a href="#" />About</a>
                    <a href="#" />Sign Up</a>
                    <a href="#" />Sign In</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i converted your code into a stack snippet, but it's still looking... off, to say the least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is caused by

```
* {
    background-color: #EAEDF5;
}
```

This will make your `.search_box` and `form` have that background color too. You can override it by using:

```
.search_box, form {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

I'd recommend removing the first rule, though, and only apply the `#EAEDF5` background color to the `body` instead of all elements.

---

**To visualize this with a concrete example:**

```css
* {
    background-color: gray;
}

#a {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: pink;
}

#c {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <div id="c">
            Hello world!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above example, the `*` selector will target all elements (all divs and the body), thus setting the background color of every div to gray. The two divs with ids `a` and `c` will override this background color, while `b` does not and get the background color it should use from the `*` selector, so it'll have a gray background color instead of the initial value of `transparent`, which would've let the pink shine through.

To fix the issue, either forcing the `#b` div to have a transparent background works or by changing the `*`-selector to `body`, which will then only color the background color of the page instead of every single element (unless overridden).

See my recommended fix in action here:

```css
body {
    background-color: gray;
}

#a {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: pink;
}

#c {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <div id="c">
            Hello world!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do I need to create a class or ID for the body then?

Comment: By simply using `body { background-color: #EAEDF5; }` you'll assign that background color to only the body (instead of every single element, which the `*` selector does).

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer!

Comment: This is a very clear answer. However, providing an 'operational' snippet might also help future readers see how this has 'fixed' this issue. Good work, though :)

Comment: @jbutler483 I've added a concrete, operational example in my answer now, thanks!